# Loop check if on last iteration?

Tags: javascript

How do I check if I'm on the last iteration of this loop? I'm sorry for asking this question. I'm used to programming in VB.NET and javascript seems very cryptic by nature.

```
if (QuerySplit.length > 1) {
   var NewQuery
   for (i=0; i<QuerySplit.length; i++)
   {
       // if we're not on the last iteration then
       if (i != QuerySplit.length) {
           // build the new query
           NewQuery = QuerySplit[i].value + " AND "
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `if (i !== (QuerySplit.length - 1)) {`

Comment: Also semi colons aren't required but highly recommended!

Comment: Not sure what this is supposed to do - you're overwriting `NewQuery` on every iteration (but the last)?

Comment: Note, you could also do like `if (i != 0) { NewQuery += " AND "; } NewQuery += QuerySplit[i].value;`.  The beginning's easier to find than the end.  :)

Comment: [What is the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take note that you need `var NewQuery = "";` and check for length - 1. Also, the last if statement is just a guess of what you probably want to do:

```
if (QuerySplit.length > 1) {
  var NewQuery = "";
  for (i = 0; i < QuerySplit.length; i++) {
    // if we're not on the last iteration then
    if (i != QuerySplit.length - 1) {
      // build the new query
      NewQuery += QuerySplit[i].value + " AND "
    } else {
      NewQuery += QuerySplit[i].value;
    }
  }
}
```

If QuerySplit.length is 4, then:

0, 1, 2, 3

...are the indexes. So you want to check for when the index is 3 and that's your last iteration.

Answer (score 19):

Your `i` is *always smaller* than `QuerySplit.length` - that's your loop condition. In the last iteration it will have a value of `QuerySplit.length-1`, that's what you can check against:

```
if (i < QuerySplit.length - 1)
```

Btw, you'd do better to use the [`join` Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for what you're trying to do:

```
var NewQuery = QuerySplit.map(function(x){return x.value;}).join(" AND ");
```

Answer (score 4):

The array is 0-based. This means if there are 3 items in the array, your indexes will be `0,1,2`. The last one is one less than the length.

You'll have to check like this: `(i < QuerySplit.length -1)`